# Failed to perform join operation when using metaprogramming in DolphinDB

Tags: metaprogramming, dolphindb

I want to add custom indicators after certain columns in a table through `join` operation using SQL metadata code. But when I executed the metacode for execution, an error was reported. Here is the script:

```
t = table(take(`A`B, 5) as sym, 2022.01.02+1..5 as date, rand(10.0, 5) as val)
fields_list = [sqlColAlias(makeCall(sum, sqlCol(`val)), `sum_val)]
sql(select=[sqlCol(`sym), sqlCol(`date), sqlColAlias(makeCall(sum, sqlCol(`val)), `sum_val)], from=t).eval() // OK
sql(select=[sqlCol(`sym), sqlCol(`date)] <-fields_list, from=t).eval() // ERROR
```

How can I modify my script? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` function:

```
sql(select=reduce(join, [sqlCol(`sym), sqlCol(`date)], fields_list), from=t).eval()
```